# Wrong analog output using PCF8591 on Android Things

Tags: android-things

Note: Since the most logical cause of malfunction is that my component is faulty I have ordered a few more. Will test on them and let you know the result.

I am expanding an existing driver for the PCF8591 Analog to Digital converter, [here's the Pcf8591 class in github](https://github.com/plattysoft/IoTAnalogReader/blob/master/pcf8591/src/main/java/com/plattysoft/pcf8591/Pcf8591.java).

Reading analog inputs works fine, but I have a strange problem when trying to write the output.

To test the driver I have a potentiometer connected to input channel 2, then I write that value to the analog output and then connect the analog output to the input 3.

The analog value only changes from 20 to around 75 for a value write from 0 to 255. I don't know if I am missing something or maybe my component is defective.

I am doing it the way it is specified by the spec sheet and also in the same way I've seen some drivers for Arduino doing it.

This is how I am writing the analog value:

```
 byte[] data = {0x40, // Control code for writing analog value
            (byte) (value)}; // Analog value
    mI2cDevice.write(data, 2);
```

I'll appreciate if someone else with this component can try and see if writing the analog value works for them.

In theory the analog output goes from AGND to VREF and I am assuming the board I have have them linked to GND and VCC. I am using this board: [image: PCF8591 image]

Comment: It may be useful to file an issue on the GitHub repo as this may depend on specific things to the driver.

Comment: I may have not been clear. I am the one writing the driver. I took an existing driver, simplified and added the analog output code.

Comment: Check the datasheet again. One similar device I was trying requested bits be in Little Endian while data is sent big Endian. You can need to do some additional conditioning to your data before transmission.

Comment: I thought about that, but when then, when i send 255 it should output 255, since that is the same in little and big endiam.